# Swift framework for all Xcode versions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-frameworks

I provide a Swift framework for my customers.
It would only work in Xcode 10.3 (Or am I doing anything wrong?)
For other Xcode, it does have Swift compatibility issues.

So I am planning to release a series of versions of my framework so that a customer with a particular Xcode version can have the respective framework version of mine.

And it is pretty complex. Because for every release or bug fix I need to generate a bunch of versions.

I just want validation if this is the right approach.

How do I simplify this?

Answer (score 2):

The compatibility issue you have is not from the version of the Xcode, is from the Swift version of the Framework. There is a difference.

In every project you can set the Swift version, but [unfortunately](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2) you can't have more than one swift version per project. The current accepted ones are `Swift 4`, `Swift 4.2` or `Swift 5`, as you can see in `Xcode` > `Target` > `Build Settings`:

[image]

Xcode 10.0 was the last version to support `Swift 3` and is [currently obsolete](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes). I wouldn't create a framework version for it.

So, I would recommend you to either focus only on the latest Swift version and create a new Framework version every time a new Swift version appears (the most common approach), or start with the current three Swift versions and give them maintenance until the Swift version is deprecated.

Comment: I would specify what you mean by current Swift versions, as Xcode 10.1 supports Swift 3, 4, 4.2 and Xcode 11.1 supports 4, 4.2, 5.

Comment: Let's add that Xcode 10.1 being [the current minimal supported version](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036), and Xcode 10.1 already supporting Swift 4.2, there is no point to offer any framework using anything lower than Swift 4.2. And starting April 2020, [Xcode 11 will become the minimal supported version](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submissions/), so there won't be any need for anything older than Swift 5.0.